# Cannot find module './data.js' in node.js/discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make an discord bot but when I want to start my bot I will get an error.

Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

I don't know why it can't find this module/

When I run "node index.js" I get the error:

> Cannot find module './data.js'

Here's my code which I use in my "index.js" it is in use for an Discord Bot.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    client = new Discord.Client({
        disableEveryone: true
    }),
    data = require('./data.js'),
    request = require('request-promise').defaults({
        pool: {
            maxSockets: Infinity
        }
    }),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    directory = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in! [${client.user.tag}]`);

    client.user.setActivity(`print("obfuscate")`, {
        type: 'PLAYING',
    })
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        async function download(url, name) {
            request.get(url)
                .on('error', console.error)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(name));
        }

        function verifyFile(file) {
            if (file.name.toLowerCase().includes("lua" || "txt")) return true;
            return false;
        }

        function shuffle(str) {
            var a = str.split(""),
                n = a.length;
        
            for(var i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
            return a.join("");
        }

        if (message.attachments.first()) {
            console.log("cool file.")
            if (verifyFile(message.attachments.first())) {
                console.log("epic file!!")
                await request.get(message.attachments.first().url).then(async (data) => {
                    fs.writeFileSync(`${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`, data)
                    var options = {
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'url': 'https://obfuscator.aztupscripts.xyz/Obfuscate',
                        'headers': {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        },
                        formData: {
                            'Input': {
                                'value': fs.createReadStream(`${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`),
                                'options': {
                                    'filename': `${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`,
                                    'contentType': null
                                }
                            },
                            'EncryptStrings': 'true',
                            'NoControlFlow': 'true',
                            'NoBytecodeCompress': 'true',
                            'EncryptImportantStrings': 'true',
                            'AddMemes': 'true'
                        }
                    };
                    request(options, function (error, response) {
                        if (error) throw new Error(error);
                        let id = shuffle(message.author.id)
                        fs.writeFileSync(`${directory}/${id}_obfuscated.lua`, response.body)
                        message.channel.send({
                            files: [`${directory}/${id}_obfuscated.lua`]
                        });
                    });

                    fs.unlinkSync(`${directory}/${message.author.id}_unobfuscated.lua`)
                    console.log("Done!")
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return;
});

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Hey i couldn't see the code,link is probably restrectid. But this case coult be the data.js directory is not the same with index.js

Comment: Can you provide a summary of your file system paths? You might want to try `data = require(path.join(__dirname,"data.js"))` also

Comment: My bad, the post has been updated (Thank you Fabian!) and you can now see the code and error.

Comment: The error says that it cannot find the module "./data.js" which means that "./data.js" does not exist. Do you know if the file exists and can you explain the paths of your project?

Comment: I don't believe the file exists. As for explaining the paths of my project, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. (I'm a novice at javascript programming, apologies if I'm missing something simple here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `data.js` either does not exist or NodeJS is unable to find it. If you don't see the file in the same folder as index.js then create it. Otherwise try using full path ex. `data = require('C:\\Users\\johnr\\Desktop\\obfuscate\\data.js')`